# Getting linkage error every time I run a soring-boot application. Anyone know the fix for that?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

This is the said error:

Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class net.javaguides.sms.StudentManagementSystemApplication
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/javaguides/sms/StudentManagementSystemApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 62.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a newer java as runtime, or compile for an older version.

Answer (score 0):

The error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/javaguides/sms/StudentManagementSystemApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 62.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 61.0
```

Indicate that your runtime is Java 17 (version 61.0), and the StudentManagementSystemApplication classes are compiled in Java 18, (version 62.0.)

Update de your java runtime and check if there is any other error